# Could nomogram be built with odds ratio or beta-coefficients only in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

I have a retrospective chart review that reported beta coefficients for both its univariate and multivariate regression analysis. However, there is no complete individual patient data. I am wondering whether there is a way to build a nomogram directly out from beta coefficients.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: How do you get regression coefficients without the data?

Comment: From published paper

Comment: Then you can create a lot of fake covariate combinations and for each one compute the predicted value from those and the published coefficients.  Use the R `rms` package `ols` function to fit the fake predictors to the predicted values, which will recover the same coefficients but create a fit object that you can feed to the `rms` `nomogram` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! It seems to work, but do you know which function/package in r to use to create fake covariate raw data? Sorry I am still super new to r.

Comment: You can pick 3 reasonable values of each continuous variable and all levels of categorical variables and use R's `expand.grid` function to generate all possible combinations of all the predictors.  For each combination evaluate the predicted values by the published model and call this your outcome variable.  Fit it with `ols(y ~ ..., data=expand.grid output)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, but I somehow still could not figure it out. I attached an example variable in the original question, would you please show me how to do it?

Comment: For that example the confidence intervals show that the coefficient estimates are not trustworthy enough to draw a nomogram.  And also you must have the intercept to do it.